# Split string ignoring html tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Is it possible to split a string by space  "" and to ignore the html tags in it ?
The html tags may have style elements like : style="font-size:14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0)" .....

The string i'm talking about is:

```
<div class="line"><span style="color: rgb(0,0,0)">John</span><u> has</u><b> apples</b></div>
```

If you can see i have space character inside the `u` tag and inside the `b` tag

What i am trying to get is the text to split as following

```
<div class="line"><span style="color: rgb(0,0,0)">John</span><u>

has</u><b>

apples</b></div>
```

I have the following regex but it does not give me the rest of the string, just the first 2 parts :

```
[\<].+?[\>]\s
```

Comment: What is the exact use case, there could be another way... edit: what are you trying to get

Comment: I think you could find space " " between ">" and "<"

Comment: I don't know how to completly ignore whitespace between < >

Comment: Someone'g gotta post it: [*Don't parse HTML with a regular expression…*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split using the following regexp:

```
str.split(/ (?=[^>]*(?:<|$))/)

[
  "<div class="line"><span style="color: rgb(0,0,0)">John</span><u>", 
  "has</u><b>", 
  "apples</b></div>"
]
```

The `?=` is a **look-ahead**. It says, "find spaces which are followed by some sequence of characters that are **NOT** greater-than signs, then a less-than sign (or end of string).

The `?:` is a **non-capturing group**. We need that here, because `split` has a special behavior: the presence of a capturing group tells it to include the splitters in the resulting array of pieces, which we don't want.