# How can I fix my code so that <strike> does not invalidate my Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, strikethrough

I'm using the following code to create fractions:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.fraction').each(function(key, value) {
    $this = $(this)
    var split = $this.html().split("/")
    if( split.length == 2 ){
       $this.html('<span class="top">'+split[0]+'</span><span class="bottom">'+split[1]+'</span>')
}    
});
});
</script>
```

If I have the following code in my body, it successfully formats as a fraction:

```
<span class="fraction">4/1</span>
```

If, however, I include a  tag, as illustrated below, the function no longer works

```
<span class="fraction"><strike>4</strike>/1</span>
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: because the tag has a "/"

Comment: Specifically your split call would return an array of length 3 and so the if below it will evaluate to false

Comment: Do you have any recommendations regarding how I can fix this in the code? I don't know how to modify the fraction code to account for this.

Comment: I'm thinking that it might be possible to write an if condition to state that if the / occurs within a tag, it should be ignored, but I don't have the skill level to begin to tackle this.

Comment: `$this.html()` -> `$this.text()`?

Comment: Depends how flexible you want to get. Maybe have a `if length == 3` part as well? Can you have more tags in there? Also, I guess you need to preserve the `strike` in the output?

Comment: @Amadan: Good call. But they probably want to preserve the `strike` tag in the output. Or maybe not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: `<strike>` is an element not supported in HTML5, use `<del>` or `<s>`...These elements will put a line right thru that 4. It won't look like `4/1`.

Comment: Changing $this.html() -> $this.text() doesn't help, unfortunately. The <strike> tag still invalidates the fraction format.

Comment: `<strike>` is HTML4 if you are asking jQuery to parse a string as if is HTML, perhaps you should use valid tags. See my last comment.

Comment: @JDoeMath It works for me. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtvct215/).

Comment: @JDoeMath i have a question. why are you doing this in javascript? basically do you have control over the page before it is served up? or are you scraping some other page you have no control over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to strip away the html tags and just get the text.

```
var split = $this.text().split("/")
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtvct215/)

If you want to keep the html markup in your result, an easy solution would be to use a different delimiter for your fraction, like a double slash `//`, a backslash `\`, or a pipe `|`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtvct215/1/)

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861440/5743988) you could also use regex to verify that it only splits if the character isn't found inside `<..>`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtvct215/5/)

```
var split = $this.html().split(/\/(?=[^>]*(?:<|$))/)
```

Comment: The alternative delimiter solution is perfect - thanks!

Comment: If you control the server-side enough to change to an alternative delimiter, why not just output the HTML you actually want directly (without the Javascript post-processing on the client)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it correctly (while preserving your markup), it gets a bit complicated due to the fact that you need a slash that is in a text node that is a direct child of the `.fraction` element; and jQuery doesn't deal with text nodes well. So:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.fraction').each(function(_, e) {
    var offset = 0, html = '<span class="top">', found = false;
    $.each(e.childNodes, function(_, c) {
      if (c.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        if (m = c.textContent.match(/(.*)\/(.*)/)) {
          found = true;
          html += m[1] + '</span>/<span class="bottom">' + m[2];
        } else {
          html += c.textContent;
        }
      } else {
        html += c.outerHTML;
      };
    });
    if (found) {
      e.innerHTML = html + '</span>';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.top {
  color: red;
}
.bottom {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="fraction"><strike>1</strike>/2</span>
<span class="fraction">2/2</span>
```